# Add onmouseover tool-tips to an R html table (based on cells in another data.frame)?

Tags: r, d3.js, htmlwidgets

I have an R matrix I want to open as an html table in the browser (maybe using the [htmlwidgets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets) package?).

There's a second matching matrix and I'd like to add the content of its cells as rollover tool-tips for the respective cells in the browser table.

Is there an existing way to pass a matrix of tool tips to a table, automatically wrapping the contents of each cell in the appropriate on.mouseover actions for a tool-tip?

Here's some code to create the source object, with a values and labels matrix, forming the cell contents and mouseover tip content respectively.

```
ncol = 4 # typically rank 1:9
n = ncol^2
values = matrix(round(rnorm(n),2), nrow = ncol, byrow = T)
labs = paste0("r", rep(1:ncol, each = ncol), "c", rep(1:ncol, times = ncol))
labels = matrix(labs, nrow = ncol, byrow = T)
free = matrix(rbinom(n= size, size = 1, prob = .5), nrow = ncol, byrow = T)

myObj = list(values = values, labels = labels, free = free)
```

Would like a function to open an ncol × ncol html table, using "values" to fill each cell and, on.mouseover, tooltips reveal the label corresponding to that cell.

For extra points, use the contents of the free matrix to color the values, with FALSE values in red and TRUE in green.

Comment: This is definitely possible.  I'll try to work something up over the next couple of days once I get an uninterrupted block of coding time.  Do you have any links to examples in mind?  How big is the matrix?

Comment: Thanks @timelyportfolio! Question updated to include example matrices of typical size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you can achieve this effect.  I tried to keep it simple to make it clearer.  We can easily add more advanced functionality and styling.  I added some styling for bonus points.

```
ncol = 4 # typically rank 1:9
n = ncol^2
values = matrix(round(rnorm(n),2), nrow = ncol, byrow = T)
labs = paste0("r", rep(1:ncol, each = ncol), "c", rep(1:ncol, times = ncol))
labels = matrix(labs, nrow = ncol, byrow = T)
free = matrix(rbinom(n= n, size = 1, prob = .5), nrow = ncol, byrow = T)

myObj = list(values = values, labels = labels, free = free)


# use formattable, htmlwidgets, and htmltools
library(formattable)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
# see what formattable gives us
formattable(myObj$values)

# now make each of our cells
#  contain information for our tooltip
m_html <- matrix(
  mapply(
    function(value, label, free){
      as.character(tags$span(
        "data-toggle"="tooltip",
        "title" = paste0(label, ": ", free),
        formatC(value, format="f", digits=3)
      ))
    },
    myObj$values,
    myObj$labels,
    myObj$free
  ),
  ncol = 4
)

browsable(
  attachDependencies(
    tagList(
      onRender(
        as.htmlwidget(formattable(m_html)),
  "
  function(el,x){
    $(el).find('[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]').tooltip()
  }
  "      
      )
    ),
    shiny::bootstrapLib()
  )
)
```

Here is a very simple way to do the above in a different way and also add the styling that you suggested.

```
# purrr could ease some of this pain
#  but wanted to avoid dependencies
formattable(
  matrix(
    formatter(
      "span",
      "data-toggle" = "tooltip",
      # use the label and free to add a simple title
      #  this can be infinitely styled and refined
      "title" = mapply(
        function(value,label,free) {
          paste0(label,": ",free)
        },
        myObj$values, myObj$label, myObj$free
      ),
      # color the background of cells based on free
      "style" = mapply(
        function(value,free) {
          if(free==1) color = "red"
          if(free==0) color = "green"
          paste0("display:block; background:",color,";")
        },
        myObj$values, myObj$free
      ),
      # values will be the text in the cells
      x~x
    )(myObj$values),
    # put back in a matrix of ncol=4
    ncol=4
  )
)
```

Comment: added another example here http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/78c668d3ba8a46f0570298bc910d1a2e